# Mercurial: How can a I make a snapshot of my working directory without doing a changeset?

Tags: mercurial, shelving

While working on a new feature I arrive at a point where it roughly works, but is still not at a point where I want to create a changeset. I would however create a "restore point" or a "snapsnot" so I can come back to this roughly working version of my codebase. In TFS I would create a shelve set.

In mercurial, shelve sets behave different: As soon as I move a file into a shelf, the file reverts to the state of the last changeset. So for my purpose of creating a snapshot and *continue* working, this behavior makes shelving not a solution.

```
How can I snapshot my work and continue with the files as they are?
```

I know there are many questions about shelving in mercurial here, but I could not find an answer to this question in them.

**Comment on the helpful answers by @Mathiasdm and @Gill Bates**

For now I go with commit --amend, which is also available in TortoisHG: the commit button can be converted to an amend button.

Ammend adds the changes to the previous commit instead of creating a new changeset. So

- first I create a *commit* with the rough version and then
- improve on it by *ammend*ing it.

"hg shelve && hg unshelve --keep" and the mq extension are nice alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One command that is particularly suited for this is:

```
hg commit --amend
```

It allows you to create a commit and keep improving it (amending it). Every time you do 'hg commit --amend', all additional changes in the working directory are added to it.

I know this does not sound 'shelve-like', but it sounds like what you need is actually not really a shelve.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve the goal:

### Shelve

You can use this command:

```
hg shelve && hg unshelve --keep
```

It will create a shelve, then unshelve it to the workspace keeping the shelve in shelve storage.

### MQ extension

There is also [MQ extension](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) which lets you manage commits as patches. You can create a snapshot with:

```
hg qnew my_snapshot_name
```

Then you will be able to refresh it, unapply, reapply, change order, convert to regular changeset and do other useful stuff, check [the link](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) for the info.

### Patch

You can save just a patch:

```
hg diff > tmp.diff
```

And then apply it with:

```
hg import tmp.diff
```

Or with:

```
patch -p1 < tmp.diff
```

Or you can import in MQ:

```
hg qimport tmp.diff
```

### Feature branch

You can adjust your VCS workflow and use so called "feature branches" to store feature-specific progress in it and not pollute a main branch with it:

```
hg branch feature/my_stufff
... work work work ...
hg commit -m 'some progress'
... polish debug finalize ...
hg commit -m 'now it really works'
```

Then you need to propagate your changes to the main branch. 
You can do that with [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) if you like to keep your history linear:

```
hg rebase -s feature/my_stuff -d default --collapse
```

It will take the whole feature branch, put in on top of default branch and collapse all the change sets of feature-branch into one changeset. Of course you can rebase without collapsing.

Or you can just merge your feature-branch to default branch:

```
hg update default && hg merge feature/my_stuff
```

This will keep non-linearity.